# Clean up Firebase event handler inside `child_added`?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In some places I've found myself nesting Firebase database listeners. For example, I have a list of `foos`, each with a list of `bars`, and I want to do something whenever a new `bar` is added to any `foo`:

```
firebase.database().ref('foos').on('child_added', function(fooSnap) {
    fooSnap.ref.child('bars').on('child_added', function(barSnap) {
        // do something with the new bar
    });
});
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

And if a `foo` is removed, is that nested `bar` `child_added` listener cleaned up, or should I be calling `.off(...)` in a `child_removed` listener somewhere? How would I even do that?

Comment: Doesn't `fooSnap.val()` contain all the children/subchildren of the new node? i.e., could you just use a synchronous loop inside?

Comment: That would work if I wanted to do something to the existing bars, but I want to continually do stuff to bars as they're added. Think notification server or search indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in a NoSQL database it is a good idea to have flatter design. For example, currently you have a structure like -

```
{
    "foos": {
        "F1": {
            "foo_data": "",
            "bars": {
                "B1": {
                    "bar_data": ""
                },
                "B2": {
                    "bar_data": ""
                }
            }
        },
        "F2": {
            "foo_data": "",
            "bars": {
                "B1": {
                    "bar_data": ""
                },
                "B2": {
                    "bar_data": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you can flatten it out like the following -

```
{
    "foos": {
        "F1": {
            "foo_data": "",
            "bars": ["B1", "B2"]
        },
        "F2": {
            "foo_data": "",
            "bars": ["B3", "B4"]
        }
    },
    "bars": {
        "B1": {
            "bar_data": ""
        },
        "B2": {
            "bar_data": ""
        },
        "B3": {
            "bar_data": ""
        },
        "B4": {
            "bar_data": ""
        }
    }
}
```

That way you do not need to nest the event handlers.